# How to reject relaying e-mail from users impersonating myself to myself

Tags: smtp, postfix, smtp-auth

Trying to use my server as a relay to send mail to another server gives you relay access denied, this is correct behavior.

```
MAIL FROM: admin@myserver
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: admin@gmail.com
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
SMTP -> ERROR: RCPT not accepted from server: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied
```

Trying to use my server as a relay to my server works for some reason.

```
MAIL FROM: admin@myserver
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO: admin@myserver
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
250 2.1.5 Ok
Sending Mail Message Body...
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
354 End data with .
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 1D80D380166
```

How do I stop this? I already have spammer spamming me with job offers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `smtp_sender_restrictions`. Allow your own network `permit_mynetworks` and/or authenticated senders `permit_sasl_authenticated` and then block any mail from your own domain name `check_sender_access`.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on SMTP authorization.

See
http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html
and
http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html

Comment: I can't get sasl to work, I tried dovecot sasl and cyrus sasl like it says in the postfix sasl readme but for some reason I can't get it work.

Here is my main.cf file 
http://pastebin.com/ec7ALtJ7

Comment: What doesn't work?  Are you getting an error or can you still send mail without authorization?